# AWS Cognito Integration with Twilio through API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, twilio, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I currently have a Lex chatbot that I would like to integrate with both Twilio and Cognito (in the sense that only Cognito authenticated users will be able to communicate with Twilio and the lex bot).

To this end, I've created an API Gateway that handles Twilio requests and pushes them to a Lambda function that interacts with Lex. I've also added a Cognito authorizer to my API Gateway that blocks users from interacting with Twilio if they are unauthenticated.

I don't currently have a back end app (long story), so for now users login to a Cognito-hosted UI that redirects to Google's homepage.

The problem? I haven't yet found a way to connect the authentication credentials given out at a user's Cognito log-in (which occurs on a web browser) to the API Gateway that communicates with Twilio (since Twilio is making the initial API calls). Currently there is no such connection, so all communication with Twilio (and therefore the lexbot) is blocked. I can't push the relevant tokens to Twilio when it makes the API call.

I have two feelings:

1. The issue probably comes from the fact that there is no connection between the web-based login and the text messages the end user sends to Twilio to kick-off the whole process
2. It seems like I will have to use a Custom Lambda Function Authorizer (I'd like to avoid this, if possible)

If it helps, I used [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/integrate-your-amazon-lex-bot-with-any-messaging-service/) as a starting point.

Any ideas?

Any and all help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The HTTP requests that Twilio makes to the API gateway are completely disconnected from your user in a browser. About the best thing you can do to exclude users that haven't signed in is to somehow store their phone number within AWS somewhere and, like you said, use a custom authorizer to check the `From` phone number on the incoming webhook matches one of your users.